# How to pass input parameters from j query dialogue box to handler file(.ashx) in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hii guys!!!
              I have a jquery dialogue box  with two input parameters which is...

```
<div id="dialog" title="Login">
<form action="" method="POST" id="loginForm">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />

</form> </div>
```

Now here is jquery dialogue event..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        SUBMIT: function() {
            $('#loginForm').submit();
        }
    }
});});
```

Now i have a handler (.ashx) file where i need to access the values of username and password...Plz guys help me how to send input parameters as URL in this case..

Any help will be highly appreciated...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: form `method = "get"` ?

Comment: @abhitalks thanks sir for ur response...but where i need to add the URL with parameters in the mentioned codes...

Comment: `<form id="loginForm" action="HANDLER_PAGE.EXT" method="GET">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a submit button on the modal. You could just use `<input type="submit" />` in your form. As for your answer, just change the method to 'get'

```
<div id="dialog" title="Login">
<form action="pathToYourHandlerFile" method="GET" id="loginForm">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />

</form> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I often consume ashx handler via ajax.
The pattern is the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url/to/the/handler.ashx',
        data: { 'param1':'param1Value', 'param2':'param2Value'  },
        success: function (data) {
            /* process the response data here */
        }
    });
```

In your case you have to pass the username and password values.